# Python - Extracting A Links with IDs

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am learning Python - Beautiful Soup by trying to scrape data. I have a HTML page with this format...

```
span id listing-name-1
span class address
span preferredcontact="1"
a ID websiteLink1

span id listing-name-2
span class address
span preferredcontact="2"
a ID websiteLink2

span id listing-name-3
span class address
span preferredcontact="3"
a ID websiteLink3
```

and so on up to 40 such entries.

I would like to get the text that is present inside those classes/IDs in the same order how they are on that HTML page.

To kick start, I tried something like this to get the listing-name-1

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=architects&locationClue=New+South+Wales&x=45&y=12")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

soup.find(span,attrs={"id=listing-name-1"})
```

It throws **An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host** error

I have no idea how to fix this. I need help on two things:

1. How to fix that error
2. How can I iterate the listing-name-1 from 1 through 40 ? I do not want to type in `soup.find(span,attrs={"id=listing-name-1"})` for all 40 Span IDs.

Thank you!

Comment: try `page.read()` and see are you able to retrieve the page content

Comment: I would first download the page to local machine, then work out the parsing part and finally if that's ready, plug in the remote file reading...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lxml.html` you can call `parse` directly with a url so you don't have to call `urllib` yourself. Also, instead of using `find` or `findall` you'll want to call `xpath` so you get the [full expressiveness of xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp); if you tried calling the same expression below using `find` it will return an `invalid predicate` error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lxml.html

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=architects&locationClue=New+South+Wales&x=45&y=12"
tree = lxml.html.parse(url)
listings = tree.xpath("//span[contains(@id,'listing-name-')]/text()")
print listings
```

will output this, preserving the order:

```
['Cape Cod Australia Pty Ltd',
'BHI',
'Fibrent Pty Ltd Building & Engineering Assessments',
 ...
'Archicentre']
```

To answer the question in your comments to my answer, what you want to search for is the `<div class="listingInfoContainer">...</div>` which contains all the info that you want. (the name, address, etc). Then you can loop over the list of div elements that match those criteria and use xpath expressions to extract the rest of the information. Note that in this case I use `container.xpath('.//span')` which will search from the current node (the container div), otherwise if you leave out the `.` and just have `//span` it will start the search from the top of the tree and you will get a list of all the elements that match, which is not what you want once you select the container node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import lxml.html

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=architects&locationClue=New+South+Wales&x=45&y=12"
tree = lxml.html.parse(url)
container = tree.xpath("//div[@class='listingInfoContainer']")
listings = []
for c in container:
    data = {}
    data['name'] = c.xpath('.//span[contains(@id,"listing")]/text()')
    data['address'] = c.xpath('.//span[@class="address"]/text()')
    listings.append(data)

print listings
```

which outputs:

```
[{'name': ['Cape Cod Australia Pty Ltd'], 
  'address': ['4th Floor 410 Church St, North Parramatta NSW 2151']}, 
 {'name': ['BHI'], 
  'address': ['Suite 5, 65 Doody St, Alexandria NSW 2015']}, 
 {'name': ['Fibrent Pty Ltd Building & Engineering Assessments'], 
  'address': ["Suite 3B, Level 1, 72 O'Riordan St, Alexandria NSW 2015"]}, 
  ...
 {'name': ['Archicentre'], 
  'address': ['\n                                         Level 3, 60 Collins St\n                                         ',
              '\n                                         Melbourne VIC 3000\n                                    ']}]
```

which is a list (again, preserving order the way you wanted) of dictionaries with the keys `name` and `address` that each contain a list. That final list is returned by `text()` which preserves the `\n` newline characters in the original html and translates things like `<br>` into a new list element. An example of why it does that is the list item, Archicentre, where the original HTML representation is:

```
<span class="address">
     Level 3, 60 Collins St
     <br/>
     Melbourne VIC 3000
</span>
```

Comment: What is the syntax for extracting links? I tried to mock your syntax like this `Website = tree.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'websiteLink')]/href()")` but it does not work.

Comment: Also, I just found that the syntax `Address = tree.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'address')]/text()")` just grabs all the content from the page that has a `<SPAN CLASS="address"...` The problem I encounter here is, not all entries/listings on the page have a Address. So, how should the case be handled where the address is not available for a given listing? The syntax `Address = tree.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'address')]/text()")` gets the output in one shot as a list. How can I check which entry out of those 40 in that page was empty? please?

Comment: @BhavaniKannan I updated my answer to address the questions you had here in the comments. I answered what I thought is the bigger issue you are trying to get at with your question. There are a number of different ways to solve the problem, but I think this one is a good, straightforward way which lets you select the subset of the HTML document that you care about and then extract the particular data you care about out of each repeating section.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan When selecting the span that contains the address I used the simpler xpath expression `//span[@class='address']` instead of `//span[contains(@class, 'address')]` because in this case I know that I want to exactly match the class called `'address'` whereas with the other example I was trying to match `'listing-name-1', 'listing-name-2', etc`, thus I used the `contains(@id,'listing-name-')` function to match a substring; strictly speaking I should have probably used `starts-with(@id, 'listing-name-'). There is no reason to use a string function unless you actually need it.

Comment: Can't believe you take so much effort in writing it down to explain things. Really amazing.... Only if I can upvote it1000000000 times. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, the point of stackoverflow is high quality questions and answers. Answering questions in detail helps me ensure that I better understand things myself. Glad I can help you out in the process.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second part is simple enough:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=architects&locationClue=New+South+Wales&x=45&y=12")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for num in range(1, 41):
    soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "listing-name-"+str(num)})
```

Comment: Lattyware, thanks you! It still throws me the same error: 
error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` Traceback started from `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents and Settings\Bhavani\Desktop\YP.py", line 6, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)`

Comment: @BhavaniKannan I ran this and it worked fine, so there must be a problem in your environment.

Comment: Lattyware, thanks again! I seriously have no clue why but this still throws me that error while that lxml solution worked fine. May be, can you point me towards what I should check for in my environment? I am on Windows XP SP2 using Python 2.7 (Idle)

Comment: I just now tried adding time.sleep(2) before page.read(). Still no luck.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a clue - it might be worth making a separate question asking this.

Comment: @BhavaniKannan I think the error you get with `page.read()` is possibly due to a problem with the `yellowpages.com.au` server that you're trying to connect to. I get inconsistent behavior when I try to connect multiple times... sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Not a whole lot you can do in your code except detect a failure and retry. You could use the [@retry decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Retry) like shown in [these examples](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/).

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem seems unrelated to python. Try printing `page.read()` and see if that gives any output. Try opening the page with your webbrowser and see if it loads.

As for your second problem, you can pass a regular expression to `findAll`:

```
import re
import urllib2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=architects&locationClue=New+South+Wales&x=45&y=12")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

listing_names = re.compile('listing-name-[0-9]+')
listings = soup.findAll('span', id=listing_names)
print(listings)
```

The above prints out all the listings on my machine so your first problem is definitely outside of your code.

Comment: Rob, The page loads fine with my web browser (Firefox) but page.read() throws an error. What I should do?